# In soccer, what's it called when the defender steals the ball by planting their foot and stopping the ball entirely?

Tags: football, terminology

In soccer, is there a name for the maneuver where a defender plants their foot directly in front of the ball?

That is, the attacker is dribbling or going for a kick and, rather than trying to steal the ball from them directly, the defender simply blocks the attacker's motion "through" the ball by stepping firmly in front of the ball. Then they run off with the ball while the attacker is regaining their balance.

I only recently started playing and it's not clear to me whether this is a variation of a common tackle, or some kind of foul. This recently happened repeatedly to my team, causing several of us (including our experienced players) to faceplant. The refs didn't seem to have an issue with it though, so I assume it must be legal.

I'd like to look up something about how to escape that move if you're the attacker (and avoid faceplanting), but I can't seem to find anything about that specific move.

Comment: It's called a tackle, but it very often can be a foul, and there is no specific way to avoid being tackled/fouled except the unhelpful "don't play football" and the slightly less unhelpful "get better at playing football".

Comment: Simple: pass the ball. If you don't have it they won't tackle you. Quick passing plays avoid a lot of challenges (and fouls/faceplants). Avoiding tackles altogether is pretty much impossible, tho.

Comment: @Nij Okay, thanks. I thought it might be a tackle, but I also thought tackles were about redirecting the ball into your control and not simply stopping it from moving. The closest common tackle I could find was the block tackle, but even that just redirects the ball without actually stopping it.

Comment: Whatever else people might think it means, the IFAB considers a tackle to be only and exactly *"[a] challenge for the ball with the foot (on the ground or in the air)"*. In particular, it does not imply any measure of success or any particular result, intended or otherwise.